Spring Security cannot ignore SOAP url and WSSecurityInterceptor
I'm developing a REST/SOAP backend in SpringBoot 2.3.12, Spring Security, JWT and cxf-rt-ws-security.
Services consumed by REST have JWT Security and SOAP services consume Rest services through the core use cases (hexagonal architecture).
SOAP services have an Interceptor that makes the security with certificates only.
The thing is that I'm controlling the token authentication of SOAP services to access to RESTs manually, thus I don't want spring security to interfere in the soap security. But still the problem persists:
0748 --- [io-8080-exec-41] org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager          : Cache 'org.apache.cxf.ws.security.tokenstore.TokenStore-117706598' created in EhcacheManager.
2024-04-23 10:39:42.285  WARN TraceId:no_request                           20748 --- [io-8080-exec-41] o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain      : Interceptor for {http://a.b.net/}AServiceImplService#{http://a.b.b.net/}Service has thrown exception, unwinding now

org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: A security error was encountered when verifying the message
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JUtils.createSoapFault(WSS4JUtils.java:238) ~[cxf-rt-ws-security-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:382) ~[cxf-rt-ws-security-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:213) ~[cxf-rt-ws-security-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2] 
.....
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.UsernameTokenValidator.verifyDigestPassword(UsernameTokenValidator.java:182) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.UsernameTokenValidator.validate(UsernameTokenValidator.java:89) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleUsernameToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:172) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:63) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.engine.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:340) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:326) ~[cxf-rt-ws-security-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]

I tried to solve the problem working on the security config rest class, telling spring security to avoid checking SOAP Interceptor by excluding the SOAP URLs to have security but the error is always the same. This is my SecurityConfig:
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(ApiPaths.LOGIN).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/services/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}

I also tried with this but nothing:
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers(IGNORED_PATHS);

}

I also don't understand why the filter is always called at register, login and every time there's a call to those URLs even though I tell spring to not do it.
